# ggplot2: consistent mapping of factor levels to line colour

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to generate several gantt chart, each with a different number of entries. I am mapping the colour of the line to a factor (source). The levels of the factor are the same for both the 'big' and 'small' charts in the example below, but when plotted the colour attributed to each level changes (ie 'radio' is green in the first, and red in the second)!

How do I ensure that all plots have the same colour mapping?

```
# Generate vectors:
name   <- paste("person", seq(10), sep = '_')
start  <- sample(seq(5), size = 10, replace = T) 
end    <- sample(seq(6,10), size = 10, replace = T)
source <- factor(c('radio','tv','radio','tv','radio','tv','book','wordofmouth','book','book')) 

# Generate data frames:
big_chart <- data.frame(name = c(name,name), value = c(start,end), source)
small_chart <- big_chart[c(1:2,11:12),]

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(big_chart, aes(value, name, colour = as.factor(source))) +
  geom_line()

ggplot(small_chart, aes(value, name, colour = as.factor(source))) +
  geom_line()
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: `ggplot(small_chart, aes(value, name, colour = source)) + geom_line() + scale_colour_discrete(drop = FALSE)`

Answer (score 0):

beetroot has provided a solution that worked perfectly for me:

```
ggplot(small_chart, aes(value, name, colour = source)) + geom_line() + scale_colour_discrete(drop = FALSE)
```